# Changing textcolor in revtex4-2

Tags: color, revtex

Since we are editing some article and in order to see everyone's contribution, we want to keep track of the changes by coloring text. However, `\userpackage{colorx}` and `\textcolor{color}` are not working in `revtex4-2`.

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: You mean `\usepackage{xcolor}` I assume?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem? I cannot reproduce your problem when setting up a small document and loading `xcolor` (not `colorx`).

Comment: somehow found the solution by trial and error using   \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}